# Running netlify dev and access .env file contents

Tags: netlify

I have a Gatsby project with a couple functions. I'd like to migrate some of my variables to `env` variables. Setting these up in Netlify is a breeze.

However, locally I'm trying to test my functions using `netlify dev`. It starts up fine, but as soon as I hit my endpoint, there are issues because I'm accessing non-existent properties on `process.env`. I have tried adding a `.env` and `.env.development` file in the root of my project (where I run `netlify dev`) but it doesn't seem to be reading them. The documentation I've ready only mentions `netlify.toml` files, but the whole point is to not have it in source control.

Is there something I need to do for the command to pick up my `.env` file?

Answer (score 0):

Configure your build to grab your `.env` and copy it over to the location that is used to deploy the website.

An example would be to add the copy step to your build command:

```
// netlify.toml
[build]
  command = "do-build && cp .env functions/"
```

Although this will only work for local deploys with the netlify command. If you want to do it with their automated deploys, there is no way around checking in the `.env` file.

To avoid that, you are expected to set those values through the project UI in Netlify's website.

> You can create environment variables in the toml file or in our UI. You might use the latter to keep sensitive values out of your repository.

https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/file-based-configuration/#inject-environment-variable-values

Comment: After adding them in the UI on the website, they get pulled down when running `netlify dev` and are available as I would expect them. In my case, sharing those values between dev and prod is ok, however I would expect most of the time they would need to have separate values. I guess the toml file could have the dev values and prod would use the UI values. Either way not super ideal... Thanks for this answer, it's certainly helpful.